# If $(X_t)$ is a Gaussian process, what is $Cov(X_s^2,X_t^2)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

Let $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb R^+}$ be a Gaussian process $\mathcal N(\mu(t), \sigma^2(t))$ with covariance function $K$.

Let $s \leq t$. Can we express $Cov(X_s^2,X_t^2)$ in terms of $K, \mu(t), \sigma^2(t), \mu(s), \sigma^2(s)$ ?

To my understanding, $(X^2_t)$ is called a chi square process. I find very little information on these processes online.

$Var(X_t^2)$ can be computed easily: $Var(X_t^2)=4 \mu^2(t) \sigma^2(t) + 2 \sigma^4(t)$.

My conjecture for the covariance is: $ Cov(X_s^2,X_t^2) = 4 \mu(t)\mu(s) K(s,t) + 2 K^2(s,t)$.

Am I right? How to prove it?

Comment: Just do the calculations, knowing that $(X_t,X_s)$ has a bivariate Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @whuber you are right, I'm stupid haha. Thank you